# Proposed change of `equals` to `==` can't be applied to Char and String?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function as below.

```
    fun process(string: String?): Int {
        if (string != null) {
            return string.filter { it.equals("a") }.length
        }
        return 0
    }
```

It shows that `it.equals("a")` could be improved, with the message
`Call replaceable with binary operator`

So I just use `Alt-Enter` to change it accordingly and get

```
    fun process(string: String?): Int {
        if (string != null) {
            return string.filter { it == "a" }.length
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Unfortunately now it error stating

`Operator '==' cannot be applied to Char and String`.

I assume this is a bug in the proposed optimization?

Comment: it is having an mistake from the beginning, because it must be `string.filter { it.equals('a') }.length` so after atl+enter it will be converted into `it == 'a'`

Answer (score 8):

Just to be sure we're on the same page, `it` is a `Char` because the `filter` method that you use operates on the string as a sequence of characters.
Therefore, `it.equals("a")` is effectively comparing a `Char` with a `String`. This can never be true, because a string can never be equal to any character, even if it contains only one. So **the code doesn't work in either case**, unless you change your string `"a"` to the *character* `'a'`.

Even if the operator `==` is compiled to the equivalent `equals()` method call, the compiler has **additional checks in the operator form** compared to explicit method calls. The error you get is because the `==` operator requires a type match, as opposed to its method counterpart `equals()`. (Since `"a"` is a string, you can't use the operator to compare it with the character `it`).

*Why the difference?* You may ask.

As far as I understood, the Kotlin team followed the Java convention for the method `equals` and left its contract permissive by allowing `Any?` as parameter. This is probably because of constraints of interoperability with Java.
However, they still saved us from this kind of mistakes with the additional type safety of the operator.

I have to admit, though, that the IDE should give you a warning for your incorrect `equals` call before asking you to replace the method call by an operator.

Comment: The question is why you can use `it.equals("a")` and not `it == "a"`.

Comment: In short, the optimization proposal is flaw for this case?

Comment: The call of equals in this case is incorrect and would never return true, so you should expect a warning from the IDE asking you to fix that call. That being said, I agree that you should first get the warning of type mismatch before the optimization suggestion.